# "God only knows" vs. "Only God knows"

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, word-order

One can say *only God knows* in reference to some mystery only an omniscient being would know, or for those who prefer their [oaths minced](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/minced-oath.html), *heaven knows* or *goodness knows* or *lord knows*.

The inverted form *God only knows* is also very common. But if read in usual English word order, it means something different, that God knows to the exclusion of anything else— God "only knows," and doesn't see, hear, act, etc.

Why and how then do we say *God only knows*? Is it a mangled quotation, a holdover from archaic English, or something else?

Comment: Definitely an idiomatic phrase, but don't ask me about the origins. Actually, if you want to know the etymology, ask at EL&U - ELL should only tell you "it's an idiom, accept it."

Comment: *Only* in *God only knows* is not an adverb but an adjective, equivalent to *alone* - and like *alone*, it is placed after the noun it modifies.

Comment: @SF I wondered about that, but thought this might be something that trips up learners. That's a good, succinct guideline for the future (unless this gets migrated).

Comment: @StoneyB You're right, but in modern English it's far more common for adjectives to precede nouns except in set phrases, so a non-native speaker could reasonably assume that only is an adjective, or that the phrase is not syntactically sound.

Comment: The phrase *God only knows* is centuries old, from a time when *only* often came directly after the word or phrase it modified, or sometimes even later in the sentence.  Although it's not as common anymore, you may still run into examples where *only* isn't placed where you'd expect it, and you should be able to understand them when you come across them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"God only knows" is an idiom. These two are equivalent.

> As to why James can't just give me a straight answer, God only knows!
>
> I really don't know why James can't just give me a straight answer!

Where the phrase comes from, and why it is inverted is probably a better discussion for ELU.

From the perspective of an English learner, you're just going to have to accept that it's an idiom, and hence you'll have to learn it by rote.

Answer (score 2):

It *can* mean "doesn't also see and hear etc", but I think you are being presumptive. In addition to word order choice, one also has an emphasis choice which does not get preserved in writing. If I place more spoken emphasis on "only" or even "god only" it becomes equivalent to "only god."

Because it has become very idiomatic, the spoken emphasis is almost unneeded because the phrase is considered understood.

{see also StoneyB's comment}

Comment: -1. "God only knows" is an idiom meaning "I don't know why this is the case". Even if it could grammatically mean "God doesn't see and hear and know; God only knows", that's a total red herring for an English learner. "God only knows" is never used by native English speakers to mean that.

Comment: You've missed the point. The construction *can* mean that, which is why the OP stated that it could and expressed confusion. The idiom *never* means that, which, if you reread what I wrote is what I said.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard people say *God only knows* in the same fashion as *goodness knows* or *lord knows*. For example,

> "*God only knows* why she's still working at that company; I would have left a long time ago."

I don't know any historical background on the phrase though.